# Growl notification like nswindow level

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, growl

I am writing a notification system just like growl. The notification is a window and it's level is set to NSModalPanelWindowLevel. The only problem is, I have a button in that window and when the user wants to click that button, he/she has to click it twice. But, for example, in growl, no matter what window you have opened, you just simply click the notification and it registers a click. 
So is it a level problem? If so, what should I set it to? Thanks

Comment: If at all possible, please don’t duplicate Growl.  Users who have Growl installed already and have multiple apps using it won’t thank you for creating yet another notification window to blot out any that they were already seeing.

Comment: My goal isn't to duplicate growl...I just simply don't want to my users to be dependent of growl, and it is for my application ONLY. I love Growl and I have no reason to duplicate it...

Comment: Sure, but, please make sure that, for users with Growl installed, you use it rather than sticking additional Growl-like pop-ups on the display.  Otherwise, you’ll blot out notifications from Growl with your notification (and possibly vice-versa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your custom controls that make up the view content of the window, you will likely want to override `NSView`'s [`-acceptsFirstMouse:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/acceptsFirstMouse%3a) method to return `YES`:

> **Discussion**
>
> The receiver can either
>   return a value unconditionally or use
>   the location of `theEvent` to determine
>   whether or not it wants the event. The
>   default implementation ignores
>   `theEvent` and returns `NO`.
>
> Override this method in a subclass to
>   allow instances to respond to
>   click-through. This allows the user to
>   click on a view in an inactive window,
>   activating the view with one click,
>   instead of clicking first to make the
>   window active and then clicking the
>   view. Most view objects refuse a
>   click-through attempt, so the event
>   simply activates the window. Many
>   control objects, however, such as
>   instances of `NSButton` and `NSSlider`, do
>   accept them, so the user can
>   immediately manipulate the control
>   without having to release the mouse
>   button.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what Growl does, but you might be able to listen for mouse over events in the window and use them to activate/deactivate the window prior to the click.  I suspect your issue is that the first click is being eaten by the activation of the window.

Just a guess on that though.

To learn how to handle mouse over events, check out this documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TrackingAreaObjects/TrackingAreaObjects.html